# How to use BotAuthentication botframework v3

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to make a proactive message according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

I can understand the way to it. I'm worried about security. So I'm trying to use **BotAuthentication**. But I don't know how to use it. I tried to add a token according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

But it seems useless. How to use BotAuthentication? By the way, do I need to worry about security?

[image]

```
using Bot.Dialogs.FAQ.Liquidation;
using Bot.Dialogs.Menu;
using Bot.Resources;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Bot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class CustomWebAPIController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/CustomWebAPI")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConversationStarter.conversationReference))
                {
                    await ConversationStarter.Resume(); //We don't need to wait for this, just want to start the interruption here

                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    resp.Content = new StringContent($"<html><body>Message sent, thanks.</body></html>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, @"text/html");
                    return resp;
                }
                else
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    resp.Content = new StringContent($"<html><body>You need to talk to the bot first so it can capture your details.</body></html>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, @"text/html");
                    return resp;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to handle bot authentication. That is done by the SDK.

You should not be using v3 as it is deprecated and no longer being developed. V4 is the current version.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) is the documentation on V4 proactive messages.

And [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) is a sample that shows how to use proactive messages.